# How to do a database-style right join on indexes without moving the indexes into the columns?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to create df3 by right joining df1 and df2 on the indexes.  This can be achieved using `merge`.  For example:

```
df3 = df1.reset_index().merge(df2.reset_index(), how='right', on=df2.index.names).set_index(df1.index.names)
```

However, I would like to be able to do this without moving the indexes into the columns.  I tried doing this with `merge`, `join`, and `concat`; however, none of the approaches I tried produced df3.

df1:

```
         data1
id1 id2       
1   1        1
2   2        2
```

df2:

```
     data2
id2       
1        1
2        2
3        3
```

df3:

```
         data1  data2
id1 id2              
1.0 1      1.0      1
2.0 2      2.0      2
NaN 3      NaN      3
```

Comment: Merge Has  left_index and right_index parameters that could be helpful. If the indices have names then you should be able to pass them to the left_on and right_on parameters. However, df3 looks unlikely to occur as you are introducing NaN into the mix

Comment: @sammywemmy  Thanks.  I tried that; however, it didn't produce df3.  I'm using a current version of pandas.